# How to make UILabel and UIButton uppercased from storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I can't find a way in the Storyboard to make my label or button text uppercased via a flag, please check my Storyboard screenshot where I show you the Attribute Inspector which has no flag for this kind:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently there is nothing ready for that, but you can add an attribute to the `Interface Builder`:

Just add this to a file, call it for example `XIB+Extension.swift`:

```
public protocol UIXIBStyle {
    var uppercased: Bool { get set }
}

extension UILabel: UIXIBStyle {
    @IBInspectable public var uppercased: Bool {
        get { return false }
        set(key) {
            if key {
                text = text?.uppercased()
            }
        }
    }
}

extension UIButton: UIXIBStyle {

    @IBInspectable public var uppercased: Bool {
        get { return false }
        set(key) {
            if key {
                setTitle(currentTitle?.uppercased(), for: .normal)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you will be able to see a new attribute called Uppercased under the `Attribute Inspector` for any `UILabel` or `UIButton`.

[image]